# Template parameters to constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, constexpr

I am trying to pass a more "generic" const input parameter to a constexpr implementation for fibonacci. When I replace the template parameter with an int, things are hunky-dory again.

```
#include<iostream>
template <typename T>
constexpr auto fib_ce(T n) {
   return (n>1) ? fib_ce(n-1)+fib_ce(n-2) : 1;
}

int main() {
   std::cout<<fib_ce(4)<<"\n";
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -o constexpr_fib constexpr_fib.cpp 
constexpr_fib.cpp:4:19: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 256
   return (n>1) ? fib_ce(n-1)+fib_ce(n-2) : 1;

              ^
```

How do I provide a template argument to a constexpr, that can take inputs like long, int, unsigned long, etc etc for this constexpr

Comment: You can work it like this to make it work: `if(n <= 1) return T{1}; return fib_ce...`.

Comment: I guess this is an issue, since it evaluates both sides of the conditional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule in [dcl.spec.auto] is:

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression,
>   the program is ill-formed.

This is to just cut short the arbitrary complexity that could be infinite recursive deduction. Fear not though, there are ways around this problem:

1. Just use `T` instead of `auto`:

   ```
   template <class T>
   constexpr T fib_ce(T n) {
       return (n>1) ? fib_ce(n-1)+fib_ce(n-2) : 1;
   }
   ```
2. We also have the rule:

   > Once a non-discarded return statement has been seen in a function, however, the return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other return
   >   statements.

   So we can use an `if` statement instead of the conditional operator. We just have to invert the logic so that the `return` statement with known type goes first:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   constexpr auto fib_ce(T n) {
      if (n <= 1) {
          return static_cast<T>(1);       // ok, deduced as T
      }
      else {
          return fib_ce(n-1)+fib_ce(n-2); // we already deduced T, so sticking with it
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I think I found the answer, need to refrain from auto and letting the compiler work the return type out here. The following works fine:

```
#include<iostream>
template <typename T>
constexpr T fib_ce(T n) {
   return (n>1) ? fib_ce(n-1)+fib_ce(n-2) : 1;
}

int main() {
   std::cout<<fib_ce(4)<<"\n";
}
```